# 'present' used as a noun like 'presence'

Tags: nouns, word-usage, legalese

I read this sentence in the full legal text of the [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/legalcode) license (emphasis mine):

> Affirmer offers the Work as-is and makes no representations or warranties of any kind concerning the Work, express, implied, statutory or otherwise, including without limitation warranties of title, merchantability, fitness for a particular purpose, non infringement, or the absence of latent or other defects, accuracy, **or the present or absence of errors**, whether or not discoverable, all to the greatest extent permissible under applicable law.

I assume the sentence is correct because it's a legal text covering <del>hundreds of</del> [about 72 million](https://stateof.creativecommons.org/) works, but I don't understand why the word "present" is used here as a noun when "presence" seems like the proper word.

These are all the definitions for "present" as a noun I found on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/present#Noun):

> - The current moment or period of time.
> - The present tense.
> - A gift, especially one given for birthdays, Christmas, anniversaries, graduations, weddings, or any other special occasions.
> - (military) The position of a soldier in presenting arms.

All of these definitions do not seem to express what I think is the meaning of the word in this context, i.e. the existence (or non-existence) of errors in the licensed work. It seems like the definition for [presence](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/presence#Noun), "The fact or condition of being present, or of being within sight or call, or at hand," fits better.

I'm not seeking legal advice or interpretations of meaning, I'm just wondering why this usage of the word is correct in this context. Which definition of "present" is being used, and why is it correct in this context?

Comment: Isn't it more likely to be a mistake?

Comment: Talking about the presence of errors this seems like perfect lawyer humor here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's the legal text a Creative Commons license, which apparently is used on some fraction of [over 1.2 billion works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons). I guess it's possible, but it seems very unlikely to me.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I found a source that said CC0 is currently used on about 72 million works so I edited the question to include that. I agree that it seems like an error at first glance but with such widespread usage for a legal document I feel like there must be a better answer.

Comment: An error, from version 1. Corrected as of version 4, perhaps earlier.

Comment: @Xanne There is no version 4 of CC0, version 1 (linked) is the latest and current version which you can see if you click "legal text" [here](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/cc0/). Your response prompted me to email the CC team asking for clarification -- I'll update as an answer if I hear back.

Comment: This, from Wikipedia Creative Commons license: "There are several types of CC licenses. The licenses differ by several combinations that condition the terms of distribution. They were initially released on December 16, 2002 by Creative Commons, a U.S. non-profit corporation founded in 2001. There have also been five versions of the suite of licenses, numbered 1.0 through 4.0.[6] As of February 2018, the 4.0 license suite is the most current."

Comment: Note that if you license something under version 1.0 or whatever, that license (errors and all) remains in effect.  I don't think there's really an ELU question to be answered here.

Comment: As far as I can tell, CC0 exists only in version 1.0 (that is what I am given when I use CC's site to public domain something.  It is not technically one of the licenses, since you are retaining no rights.

Comment: @Xanne If you think there is a later version, why don't you link it? I have checked the website and confirmed that there is no later version available, maybe for the reasons that Cuagau expressed. CC0 is technically a license though at least in jurisdictions where the concept of PD doesn't exist, albeit it only "replicates" PD to the best of its ability.

Comment: It seems to me that, as with all PD work, there's no warranty against errors.

Comment: the presence or absence of errors, not present and absence of. Clearly a mistake. This is not rocket science (yet).

Comment: @Lambie The mistake is noted on the errata here, thanks all for the responses: https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Legalcode_errata#CC0_.281.0.29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to Version 4 of the Creative Commons license, with the error (present instead of presence) corrected.

https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode

Here's a link https://creativecommons.org/2011/04/15/plaintext-versions-of-creative-commons-licenses-and-cc0/ to plain text versions of the various licenses.  These seem to be version three (I'd say the web site is difficult to navigate); the CC0 has not changed and includes the error.

Documents in which a set of similar phrases and text is used over and over are subject to error because it becomes extremely difficult for proofreaders to catch the errors; we tend to see what we expect.  The brain is faster than the eye.

When proofreaders read wedding announcements for a newspaper, they proof them by reading them out loud (to each other) backwards.  One method for finding errors.

Also keep in mind that while these are licenses one can adopt to give permission of one kind or another for use, the development of the licenses is a primarily  volunteer or pro bono activity perhaps more subject to error than paid work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's good to know that my confusion about that sentence was well-founded. As a frequent CC user and supporter, being honest I just asked this question for fun looking to get proven wrong -- so I have to admit I'm shocked that a typo in a legal text used over 72 million times could go unnoticed for about ten years. I'll update when I hear back from the CC team via email, and maybe this post can ultimately result in an improvement!

Comment: If you could please edit your answer just to clarify that your linked license (CC-BY) is a different text than the one this question is about though (the latest and current version of CC0) and not an upgrade or later version, I'll be happy to accept it!

Comment: There is another point here: once a license is accepted, it shouldn't be changed (perhaps cannot legally be changed) without "both" parties signing off (initializing).  Given that this is a digital license and the people/organization/parties using it cannot all be contacted, it simply is what it is.  There can be newer versions to be adopted in the future, but each version is what it is.  So there is no improvement that's acceptable.

Comment: Yep, turns out it's on the errata, my bad all and thanks for the responses: https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Legalcode_errata#CC0_.281.0.29